# Can ibeacon communicate with ibeacon?

Tags: ibeacon

If I have three ibeacons B1, B2 and B3,
B1 connect to B2
B2 connect to B3

Can B1 know the B3 ibeacon is exist?

Maybe B2 repeat the message from B1 to B3 ? Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beacons are only senders, they just broadcast their (unique) id.
With your app you can read the id and do a specific action.

Some beacons also collect data like the temperature, that you can read when connected.

[Apples Getting Started with iBeacon](https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/Getting-Started-with-iBeacon.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

> Can B1 know the B3 ibeacon is exist?

Technically it could, but this is most likely not implemented. By design beacons are just... beacons and there are no much benefit from making them aware of presence of other beacons.

Comment: if it is not implemented, is it possible I write some code to do it.
Or it is the limitation of hardware?

Comment: There's usually no hardware needed for 2 way communication.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a "Beacon Mesh", where interconnected devices use an antenna to broadcast and another to connect to the next link in the chain. This way, you could connect all your beacons to the internet via only one beacon that is connected.

When you asked the question, I think this concept was only academic, but it seems to now have been worked into a full solution by people like http://www.ubudu.com/

Typical uses for beacons are proximity however, as this is just receiving and processing a series of IDs in a given "region"

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is possible by relaying information via [Bluetooth GATT](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/generic-attributes-overview). There are APIs on most devices that make this easier than it seems from the specs.

Also take a look at the new [Bluetooth Beacon Mesh](https://www.bluetooth.com/news/pressreleases/2017/07/bluetooth-sig-announces-mesh-networking-capability).